# How do Structures with Inheritance (:>) work in Coq?

Tags: coq, coercion

I am having a hard time understanding the mechanism of [structures with inheritance](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual021.html) (18.9) in an example (and coercion in Coq in general).

From a paper about MathClasses, there is an example of structure with inheritance (:>) between `SemiRing` and `CommutativeMonoid`:

```
Class SemiRing A {e: Equiv} {plus: RingPlus A} {mult: RingMult A}
  {zero: RingZero A} {one: RingOne A}: Prop :=
{
   semiring_mult_monoid:> CommutativeMonoid A (op:=mult)(unit:=one)
 ; semiring_plus_monoid:> CommutativeMonoid A (op:=plus)(unit:=zero)
 ; semiring_distr:> Distribute mult plus
 ; semiring_left_absorb:> LeftAbsorb mult zero 
}.
```

I understand that mathematically, the multiplication and addition operations (`semiring_{mult,plus}_m`) in a SemiRing is each a `CommutativeMonoid`. Also, the the classes `SemiRing` and `CommutativeMonoid` are predicate functions similar to conjunction `/\`.

From the manual linked above,

> If ident_i:>term_i, then ident_i is automatically declared as coercion
>   from ident to the class of term_i.

But I don't see how this works computationally in the example above. In terms of order, do we prove that something `A` is a `SemiRing` first, or do we prove `CommutativeMonoid A` first?

After we prove one of these two properties of `A`, do we also need to prove the other? If not, how can Coq automatically deduce that using the declaration above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, so to say, either way. Let's build an instance of the `SemiRing` typeclass for the natural numbers. The first variant can be found in the MathClasses library ([here](https://github.com/math-classes/math-classes/blob/751e63b260bd2f78b280f2566c08a18034bd40b3/implementations/peano_naturals.v#L14)). *Note*: I've installed a recent MathClasses version via [OPAM](https://opam.ocaml.org), so some names are a bit different.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import MathClasses.interfaces.abstract_algebra.

Instance nat_equiv: Equiv nat := eq.
Instance nat_plus: Plus nat := Peano.plus.
Instance nat_0: Zero nat := 0%nat.
Instance nat_1: One nat := 1%nat.
Instance nat_mult: Mult nat := Peano.mult.

Instance: SemiRing nat.
Proof.
  repeat (split; try apply _); repeat intro.
         now apply plus_assoc.
        now apply plus_0_r.
       now apply plus_comm.
      now apply mult_assoc.
     now apply mult_1_l.
    now apply mult_1_r.
   now apply mult_comm.
  now apply mult_plus_distr_l.
Qed.
```

We can see here, that we've proved all the properties we need for `SemiRing`s. And we've done it without building intermediate instances for `CommutativeMonoid`, `Monoid`, etc. -- all the way up to `Setoid`.
Because of the coercion mechanism we can use our `SemiRing nat` as an instance of *any* of the "predecessor" typeclasses:

```
Goal @CommutativeMonoid nat _ plus 0. Proof. apply nat_semiring. Qed.
Goal @Monoid nat _ mult 1. Proof. apply nat_semiring. Qed.
Goal Setoid nat. Proof. apply nat_semiring. Qed.
```

But if we ask Coq to print instances of the `Monoid` typeclass (`Print Instances Monoid.`), then we won't find those two instances we've *implicitly* built.

The above could be called a top-down approach: we build an instance of the most expressive typeclass and then we get the ability to use it as a more abstract entity.

---

The other way is to use the bottom-up approach: we start with the least expressive typeclass and gradually build our instances up to the most expressive typeclass.

```
(* ... boilerplate skipped ... *)
Ltac deduce_fields := split; try exact _; try easy.

Instance: Equivalence nat_equiv.
  deduce_fields. Qed.
Instance nat_setoid: Setoid nat.
  unfold Setoid. deduce_fields. Qed.
Instance nat_semigroup_plus: @SemiGroup nat _ plus.
  deduce_fields. exact plus_assoc. Qed.
Instance nat_semigroup_mult: @SemiGroup nat _ mult.
  deduce_fields. exact mult_assoc. Qed.
Instance nat_monoid_plus: @Monoid nat _ plus 0.
  deduce_fields. exact plus_0_r. Qed.
Instance nat_monoid_mult: @Monoid nat _ mult 1.
  deduce_fields. exact mult_1_l. exact mult_1_r. Qed.
Instance nat_comm_monoid_plus: @CommutativeMonoid nat _ plus 0.
  deduce_fields. exact plus_comm. Qed.
Instance nat_comm_monoid_mult: @CommutativeMonoid nat _ mult 1.
  deduce_fields. exact mult_comm. Qed.
Instance nat_semiring: SemiRing nat.
  deduce_fields. exact mult_plus_distr_l. Qed.
```

If we now

```
Print Instances Monoid.
```

we get

```
(* ... *)
nat_monoid_plus : Monoid nat
nat_monoid_mult : Monoid nat
(* ... *)
```

since we've built (and named) the instances explicitly. A quick example:

```
Goal @Monoid nat _ plus 0.
  exact nat_monoid_plus.    (* apply nat_semiring works too *)
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to read this declaration is:

```
Class SemiRing A {e: Equiv} {plus: RingPlus A} {mult: RingMult A}
  {zero: RingZero A} {one: RingOne A}: Prop :=
{
   semiring_mult_monoid : CommutativeMonoid A (op:=mult)(unit:=one)
 ; semiring_plus_monoid : CommutativeMonoid A (op:=plus)(unit:=zero)
 ; semiring_distr       : Distribute mult plus
 ; semiring_left_absorb : LeftAbsorb mult zero 
}.
```

plus the corresponding coertions:

```
Coercion SemiRing A ...   >-> CommutativeMonoid A ...
Coercion SemiRing A _ m p >-> Distribute m p
```

etc...